# SQL Server Reporting Service (SSRS) - Calculate Percentage using values in two columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

I am attempting to calculate the % using the sum of two columns. I have included an IIF statement at the beginning to also show '-' instead of '0' if a value does not exist. The values in LLActive and LLClosed are equal to 1 or 0 hence the COUNT function.

Output should be 100%.

```
=IIF(SUM(Fields!LLActive.Value) + SUM(Fields!LLClosed.Value)=0,"-", COUNT(IIF(Fields!LLActive.Value=1 OR Fields!LLClosed.Value=1,1,0))/COUNT(Fields!LLActive.Value) + COUNT(Fields!LLClosed.Value))
```

Comment: You question is a bit vague. Are you attempting to format the output or does you calculation not work? You can add a format specifier of "P0" to force percentage.

Comment: Thanks @RossBush my calculation does not work. would the format specifier contain in the second argument?: 'COUNT(IIF(Fields!LLActive.Value=1 OR Fields!LLClosed.Value=1,1,0))/COUNT(Fields!LLActive.Value) + COUNT(Fields!LLClosed.Value))'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a **SUM** instead of COUNT for the 1/0 IIF (line 3). You are Counting 1 and 0 which will count all values.

```
=IIF(SUM(Fields!LLActive.Value) + SUM(Fields!LLClosed.Value)=0,
    "-", 
    SUM(IIF(Fields!LLActive.Value = 1 OR Fields!LLClosed.Value = 1, 1, 0)) 
    / 
    COUNT(Fields!LLActive.Value) + COUNT(Fields!LLClosed.Value))
```

Comment: thanks @Hannover Fist.  This was my issue. Answer marked as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this calculation in the script used by the Report.

C1: Add a column for the SUM of all Actives and Closed

C2: Add another column for the expresion in 2nd IIF

Then do in the Report:

IIF(C1=0, "-", IIF(C2=1, 1, 0) / C1))